# Assume role not returning values

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab-ci, amazon-iam

I'm trying to use assume role for an assignment and I wanted to test if my assume role works. This is my script.

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy_stack:
  stage: deploy
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  #This is due to the amazon/aws-cli image's entrypoint being: /usr/local/bin/aws. When you run aws by itself locally, it'll return the help message and give a 252 exit code. To override the entrypoint,
  script:
    - aws sts assume-role --role-arn "$ROLE_ARN" --role-session-name "MyRoleSession" > assumed_role.json
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId' assumed_role.json)
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey' assumed_role.json)
    - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken' assumed_role.json)
    - echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
    - echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
    - echo "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"
    - return 0
    #- aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name MyNginxStack --template-body ./cf-template.yml --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Error i received

```
Getting source from Git repository 00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/louisdec95/load-balanacer-nginx/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 228b7839 as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ git remote set-url origin "${CI_REPOSITORY_URL}"
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01
Using docker image sha256:086c23dd662ad126dfcb06357c916b8659fd59021d6f3eae1b242ba11f774650 for amazon/aws-cli with digest amazon/aws-cli@sha256:16c5a4e1022a04208561d571b36615fe207e56c725b0d83f60b63729783f4415 ...
$ aws sts assume-role --role-arn "$ROLE_ARN" --role-session-name "MyRoleSession" > assumed_role.json
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Is my script wrong to assume role?

Comment: You need some kind of source credentials (with `sts:AssumeRole` permission) or OIDC setup to be able to assume a role. The operation is failing because no source credentials are configured.